# Using include inside range in Go templates (helm)

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have a template that get rendered several times with a `range` iteration and I can access variables external variables such as `$.Release.Name` without a problem. However, when I include templates I can't get it to work:

```
{{ range $key, $val := $.Values.resources }}
      ...
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/secrets.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
{{ end }}
```

And in `secrets.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Secret"
metadata:
  name: {{ $.Release.Name }}-secrets
```

I got this error:

```
Error: render error in "botfront-project/templates/deployment.yaml": template: [filename] :19:28: executing [filename] at <include (print $.Template.BasePath "/secrets.yaml") .>: error calling include: template: .../secrets.yaml:4:19: executing ".../secrets.yaml" at <$.Release.Name>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.Name
```

How do I access variables inside an included template?

Answer (score 69):

## TL;DR;

just replace `.` with `$` to use the global scope instead of the local one you created .

Example:

```
{{- include "my-chart.labels" $ | nindent 4 }}
```

## Explanations

According to the docs, https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#modifying-scope-using-with:

> we can use $ for accessing the object Release.Name from the parent
> scope.
> $ is mapped to the root scope when template execution begins
> and it does not change during template execution

With `range` we change the scope inside the loop. Indeed, `{{- include "my-chart.labels" . | nindent 4 }}` would invoke the current scope `.`.

So if you dig into this "scope" thing in helm doc, you eventually find this part: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/

With this example:

```
{{- range .Values.tlsSecrets }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}
  labels:
    # Many helm templates would use `.` below, but that will not work,
    # however `$` will work here
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ template "fullname" $ }}
    # I cannot reference .Chart.Name, but I can do $.Chart.Name
    helm.sh/chart: "{{ $.Chart.Name }}-{{ $.Chart.Version }}"
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: "{{ $.Release.Name }}"
    # Value from appVersion in Chart.yaml
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "{{ $.Chart.AppVersion }}"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: "{{ $.Release.Service }}"
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: {{ .certificate }}
  tls.key: {{ .key }}
---
{{- end }}
```

Comment: This is working. I can't thank you enough, sir.

Comment: No problem, really useful when you use ranges :)