# Access sealed secret from deployment.yaml in helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I'm trying to use a helm chart to deploy my secrets as sealed secret, I have created a template for the sealed secret

```
apiVersion: bitnami.com/v1alpha1
kind: SealedSecret
metadata:
  name: {{ include "api.fullname" . }}
  namespace: api
  
spec:
  template:
    metadata: 
      name: {{ include "api.fullname" . }}
  encryptedData:
    {{- range $key, $val := .Values.encryptedData }}
    {{ $key }}: {{ $val }}
    {{- end }}
```

and in my deployment I'm setting the secret values as env variables

```
env:        
{{- range $key, $val := .Values.encryptedData }}
- name: {{ $key }}
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: {{ include "sealedsecret.bitnami.com/api.fullname" $ }}
      key: {{ $key }}
{{- end }}
```

The problem is when I install the chart the sealed secret file is in sealedsecret.bitnami.com/api

how can reference that in the include part of the secretKeyRef

The error I'm getting when installing the chart

```
Error: template: joe-api/templates/deployment.yaml:42:25: executing "api/templates/deployment.yaml" at <include "sealedsecret.bitnami.com/api.fullname" $>: error calling include: template: no template "sealedsecret.bitnami.com/api.fullname" associated with template "gotpl"
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SealedSecret creates Secret in your cluster with the same name as itself, see https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets#overview

Your SealedSecret name comes from chart fullname template - `{{ include "api.fullname" . }}`, but in deployment you are including undefined template, named `sealedsecret.bitnami.com/api.fullname` (you can check available templates in `templates/_helpers.tpl` file if you want)

So the snippet below should work:

```yaml
env:        
{{- range $key, $val := .Values.encryptedData }}
- name: {{ $key }}
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: {{ include "api.fullname" $ }}
      key: {{ $key }}
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I'm still getting an error template: api/templates/deployment.yaml:41:25: executing "api/templates/deployment.yaml" at <include "api.fullname" .>: error calling include: template: no template "api.fullname" associated with template "gotpl"

Comment: Ah, i always forget scope inside `range`, replaced `.` with `$`, should be fixed see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61297149/using-include-inside-range-in-go-templates-helm

Comment: I'm still getting the error

Comment: How did you create your chart? Have you used `helm create api` to generate boilerplate chart? Do you have file `templates/_helpers.tpl`? Do you have `api.fullname` template defined inside it?

Comment: yes I created it with helm create and I have the _helpers.tpl and in there there's an api.fullname

Comment: sorry I had a mis spelling, it works now. thanks